# elasticsearch: On premise restore snapshot from aws s3

Tags: aws, elasticsearch

This could sound pretty straightforward. However, I've spent days looking in the web for a method where I can migrate snapshot from aws s3 to on premise elasticsearch cluster.

All the docs I've found mentioning how to achieve this for es on cloud, where Kabana console is available. This [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-migrate-from-aws.html#ec-migrate-from-aws-es-2-2a) for instance is an example.

Can anyone advise me how can I achieve this? noting that:

Snapshot taken, and a repo already exist within `aws s3` bucket. 7

O.S: Centos 7

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party;
Not sure what version of Elasticsearch you're using;
This requires your premise cluster to be able to access (via network FS or otherwise) the snapshot repository.

Generally speaking, if you have access to the snapshot repo directly with your premise cluster, you will need to actually register the repository first following the instructions on the following:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/put-snapshot-repo-api.html

After doing this, either via Kibana Dev Tools or using curl/equivalent tool (There's a copy as cURL option on the doc codeboxes) you can use this link as a reference to actually perform the restore operation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/restore-snapshot-api.html

**Some tips**

Make sure the documentation matches the version(s) of elasticsearch you're using.

If there's version mismatch (mainly major version but not always) between your aws cluster and your premise cluster, you should reference
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore.html
to ensure that you are running a version of elasticsearch on premise which is able to load your aws snapshot.

Your data and your master nodes need to have access to the snapshot repository; When you go to "create" the repository on your premise cluster it will fail if this is not the case.

All of the premise/on-site documentation for elasticsearch contains cURL statements in the docs for all example API usage. (Little wrench in bottom right)